# How to express that I don't need more comparisons for my thesis?

Tags: word-choice

I defined a vast set of experimental settings and created charts for their respective performances as part of my Master's thesis. I compare three sets of two settings in my evaluation to answer my research questions. My advisors asked me to address why I only have three comparisons when I could've compared so much more. Here's my attempt at doing so:

> We refrain from additional comparisons of experimental settings and their carts because the ones presented above are sufficient to sustain our core hypotheses.

English is not my native language and I'm not confident in my choice of "sustain" and "core hypotheses". I'm looking for confirmation on the choices I made or alternatives better suited to convey the intended meaning.

Comment: At first I thought my question should be labeled "word-choice" but as per its documentation, I would've had to include a list of words to choose from. Then I selected "single-word-requests" instead. Please propose a better tag if this is still not a good choice, thank you!

Comment: This looks like Off Topic proofreading to me. But yeah - it's fine to talk about the *[evidence, whatever] [**needed to sustain the hypothesis***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22needed+to+sustain+the+hypothesis%22), as many written instances in that link will show.

Comment: The rules allow proof-reading if "the source of concern is clearly specified" and I believe my question meets that criteria. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: I intend no criticism of you personally for posing the question here (I've provided the reassurance you seek anyway). I just don't think this question is likely to be useful to future visitors. Note that *in principle* you could have conducted the same search into Google Books that I did above, and since all you *actually* need to know here is that ***sustain*** has often been used in exactly this context, I could have closevoted for "lack of prior research". (But I didn't! :)

Comment: @oschlueter You need to explain what you think is *wrong* with the words **sustain** and **core hypotheses** in the context of the sentence, and what other words you've already considered and rejected, and why. Without that explanation, it is indeed seemingly just asking for proofreading.

Comment: Might be better asked in [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @oschlueter Also, `word-choice` is the best tag, and I've put it back. The deficiency is in the question itself, which is not giving any limitation of choice. A word doesn't need to be picked from those specifically in a list (a list can be all the words in a dictionary), but at least some alternatives need to be provided in the question, so as to indicate the type of thing being considered. Note, too, that this isn't just about dropping in a different word, but possibly rephrasing the sentence to accommodate other words and the associated grammar.